# Change font type in LaTex (Overleaf)

Tags: books, overleaf, garamond

I started using LaTex to write a document (documentclass book) and I am still learning.
I have tried to change the font type to Garamond (Microsoft Word) using the following code:

```
\usepackage[]{babel}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

However, the text is still written with the default type font. What am I doing wrong? Can I write a document with Garamond font?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi Lcs, the URW Garamond font is not available on Overleaf by default, because it is non-free software: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/garamond/ You might try ebgaramond, a free software clone of Garamond, instead: https://ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond

Comment: Hello Paul, thanks for your answer. I tried this code, but the font type of my text did not change... \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openright, twoside]{book} 

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\usepackage[]{babel}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage[ebgaramond]{mathdesign}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}

Comment: ebgaramond is a separate package; it's not a package option for the mathdesign package. Check the Readme file on CTAN for details of how to use it: https://ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond

Comment: Thank you, Paul. Ebgaramond looks a bit different from Garamond font (Microsoft Word) ... Do you know the best font type I can use in LaTex to get the Garamond (Microsoft Word)?

Comment: If you own the Garamond font, you can upload the .otf or .ttf font files to your Overleaf project to use it in Overleaf with the XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX compiler engine settings. See our help article here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F

Comment: No, I don't have it. Can I obtain this font type for free?

Comment: There are many different variants of Garamond, some of them free and others not free. Not knowing which specific variant you're using in MS Word, I can't say if you can get a copy for free. If it's available in MS Word on your computer, it's probably already installed on your system, which means you can access a copy of the font file. But this is getting extremely far afield from the question and the scope of this site... :-)